# Netty 4.0 - Close Channel on Invalid Input

Tags: java, netty, nio

Basically I have the following decoder:

```
public class Decoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Packet, Void> {

@Override
public Packet decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    short id = in.readUnsignedByte();
    Packet packet = Packet.newInstance(id);
    if (packet == null) {
        throw new IOException("Wasn't prepared to deal with packet 0x" + Integer.toHexString(id));
    }
    packet.read(in);
    return packet;
}
```

}

It is designed to take input from the stream, read an unsigned byte packet id and then use that byte to construct a decoder, however the issue I have here is shutting down the system on an invalid input (where the IOException is thrown). I have tried using ChannelHandlerContext.close() and ChannelHandlerContext.channel().close() however both of these end up calling the Decoder in a loop and I land up getting stuck.

Please give me some help in gracefully closing this connection.

On a side note it would also be nice to know how to terminate a connection when a read has blocked for more than x milliseconds.

Comment: Seems I solved most of it by using:`    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        Channel c = ctx.channel();
        if (c.isOpen()) {
            System.err.println("Caught Exception: ");
            cause.printStackTrace();
            c.close();
        }
    }` to close the socket, however my threads still seem to be hanging round.

Comment: Ok, I figured out that the threads were sticking round because they don't cache like normal Executors do, however I would still like to know how I can get an event when the socket has received no read for X seconds.

Answer (score 1):

To close inactive connections you could add a `ReadTimeoutHandler` to your pipeline. The timeout handler will throw a `ReadTimeoutException` when no data was received within the specified time period. You can handle this exception in the `exceptionCaught()` method in the same way as you handle the `IOException` on invalid input.

Comment: Thanks, I added that as a test, however wasn't sure if it would work, (I haven't written enough of the server to get this to occur yet). I will add a timeout handler back into my code, with Netty 4 is there any cleanup of this handler I need to do?

Comment: The `ReadTimeoutHandler` is pretty much the same in Netty 4. BTW: you could open a TCP connection with Telnet to your server to see if the timeout handler works.